# My VS Code has over 10k commits for no reason

Tags: git, visual-studio

For some reason I have over 10k commits in my vs code. [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn9Ze.png). I did not do a single thing and got greeted by this...
What sould i do? Sould I just commit the changes or something else??

Comment: You mean you have a lot of changes, so a lot of commits. Smells like a newline conversion to me. No, don't commit, there are better ways to deal with this.

Comment: To rephrase what @joanis said in the first comment: that's not 10000 *commits*. That's 10000+ *changed files* in your working tree. Based on the first few file names, it looks like you created a Git repository in your home directory, which is something nobody should ever do (well, hardly ever?).

Comment: See [Why do I have so many untracked files on Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63124528/1256452) and its mis-titled linked duplicate []How to remove all local files that were accidentally added to the git system(https://stackoverflow.com/q/62244042/1256452).